# PHP GD Image generation broken

Tags: php, gd, captcha

I need help in my PHP image code. I'm trying to make Captcha, but all I get is broken image icon ?

This is my code:

```
<?php 
header('Content-type: image/jpeg'); 

$text = "1111"; 
$font_size = 30; 

$image_width = 110; 
$image_height = 40; 

$image = imagecreate($image_width, $image_height); 
imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255); 
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0); 

imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, 15, 30, $text_color, 'font.ttf', $text); 
imagejpg($image); 
?>
```

"font.ttf" is next to my php file, and names are matching

Comment: I don't know where you got this script. But i shall recommend you to go on with the working code here http://www.w3schools.in/php/captcha/

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
imagejpeg($image);
```

Instead of

```
imagejpg($image);
```

[As `imagejpg()` doesn't exist.](http://php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=imagejpg&lang=en&scope=404quickref)

When debugging you should comment out the header to see the errors.